# Copy email in iPhone application

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6

Can I copy/open email from my iPhone device email application within my application .

Thanks,
Sunil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. 3rd party apps have no access to a user's emails or email account information.